# A query pertaining conversion of edittext to int functionality in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-edittext, int

I'm new to Android Studio. So I have an edittext with an id of edittext1. I want to create a variable, x, which will be equal to the numeric input which is made by the user inside of the box. I can manipulate this later. I then want to show that input as the text of a different edittext, named edittext 2. How would I do this?
This is what I have so far

```
    EditText a = (EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    EditText b = (EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.editText2);

public void buttonOnClick (View v){
    int x = parseInt(a.toString());
    Button button=(Button) v;
    b.setText(x);
}
```

The app crashes when I click the button.

And I already did android:inputType="phone" to ensure that the input is numeric.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Use a.getText().toString() instead of a.toString().

Comment: Thanks, now I am getting a different error saying Cannot resolve method 'ParseInt (java.lang.String)'
It told me to make a static import method, so this came up at the top:

import static java.lang.Integer.parseInt;

However, the program still crashes when I try opening it and it says this in the log cat:

 java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find a method buttonOnClick(View) in the activity class sahilshah.finalscalculator.FinalCalculator for onClick handler on view class android.widget.Button with id 'button'